# Probability Mass Function of largest number selected without replacement

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Objects are numbered 1 to $x$. If $y$ of them are randomly selected without replacement, find the pmf of $R_{yx}$, where $R_{yx}$ is the largest number selected and $y<x$.

So far I have: Probability of being selected = $1/n$ but I just don't understand Probability Mass Function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R_{yx}=x-1$, you select $y-1$ objects out of $\{1,2,\ldots,x-2\}$ objects other than $x$ and $x-1$. The remaining one object must be $x-1$. Extending this in general,

$$P(R_{yx}=x-k)=\frac{x-k-1\choose y-1 }{x \choose y}\ \forall\ 0\le k\le x-y$$